# Problems producing and consuming messages from/to kafka AWS MSK with dot net core serverless application

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, aws-msk

I'm trying to create a producer API which should just grab the body of the request and send it to a kafka topic in an MSK cluster. (the problem is pretty the same for the consumer part)

I created the MSK cluster in a VPC with 3 dedicate subnetworks.
The serverless application is running into the same VPC but another subnet adding the VpcConfig into the 'serverless.template' file.
I am also attaching the policies "AWSLambdaFullAccess" and "AmazonMSKFullAccess" on that file.
The security groups on both sides are allowing all traffic in all ports.

I create an EC2 instance in the same subnet, and I can successfully connect using the command 'bin/kafka-console-producer.sh' and create messages.

My dotnet core is using the package "Confluent.Kafka" version 1.3.0.

Code looks like:

```
            var config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = this.BootstrapServers };
            using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Logger.LogInformation($"Producer name: {p.Name}");

                    var dr = await p.ProduceAsync(this.TopicName, new Message<Null, string> { Value = message });

                    this.Logger.LogInformation($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
                }
                catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
                {
                    var msg = $"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}";
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    this.Logger.LogCritical(msg);
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to set the bootstrap servers with the DNS provided directly from MSK and also adding the prefix "plaintext://"

Any idea why I am getting a TimeOut in the "ProduceAsync" line?

My guess is this is because the library "Confluence.Kafka" is not compatible somehow with MSK, but I don't really find if that's true or not.

Thank you beforehand.

Kind regards,